# Select the drawn circle and move with the help of cursor in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have drawn a circle in framelayout, now i want to select it and move anywhere in the frame layout. How to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly if check the position where user touch on the screen using its finger and check whether it's in circle or not. If it is in circle radius then get the circle center point and user point to calculate the distance of them this will be doing in onTouch() method with the Down event time.

so now you get the user touch location with the distance of the circle center now on move time get the new location point and add the distance in that new location point and redrawn the circle with new points